# NHibernate - Self referencing mapping interferes with foreign key mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following classes:

```
public class Track
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Track MainMix { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Track> SubMixes { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<FileVersion> Files { get; set; }
}

public class FileVersion
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Track Track { get; set; }        
}
```

And the following mappings:

```
public class TrackMap : ClassMap<Track>
{
    public TrackMap()
    {
        Id(x=>x.Id);
        References(x => x.MainMix);
        HasMany(x => x.SubMixes)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .KeyColumn("MainMix_id");    
        HasMany(a => a.Files)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.All();        
    }
}

public class FileVersionMap : ClassMap<FileVersion>
{
    public FileVersionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Track);
    }
}
```

There is omitted code for the sake of simplicity. The Track table has a "MainMix_id" column that is a self referencing column for a parent/child relationship among Track records.
When I try to fetch a track from the database the NHProfiler tells me that Nhibernate tries to fetch the fileversions of that track with the following query:

```
SELECT files0_.MainMix_id as MainMix9_1_,
       files0_.Id         as Id1_,
       files0_.Id         as Id9_0_,
       files0_.Track_id   as Track8_9_0_
FROM   [FileVersion] files0_
WHERE  files0_.MainMix_id = 3 /* @p0 */
```

It seems like it has confused the parent id column of the Track table with its primary key column. When I remove References(x => x.MainMix) from the Track mapping the query is correct, but I don't have the parent track record returned.

Let me know if I can clarify this any more and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does this make a difference?

TrackMap :

```
References(x => x.MainMix).Column("MainMix_id");
```

FileVersionMap :

```
References(x => x.Track).Column("Track_id");
```

Comment: Good thinking @jenson-button-event but I am afraid the query is the same. No difference.